# awk '{printf "%d ", 49420877107}' print the wrong number 2147483647

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I run the same shell code **awk '{printf "%d ", 49420877107}'**  on different pc, however get different answer .

---

PC one
[Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UtwKv.png)

```
awk --version
GNU Awk 4.1.3
```

[System Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/izAkk.png)

---

PC two
[Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFjew.png)

```
awk --version 
awk:not an option
awk -W version
mawk 1.3.3 Nov 1996, Copyright (C) Michael D. Brennan
compiled limits:
max NF             32767
sprintf buffer      2040

awk '{printf "%d ", 49420877107}'
2147483647
```

[System Information](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JKf6h.png)

---

Is there anybody know the reason ? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are you aware that posting pictures of text often acts as an invitation for downvotes?

Comment: Please add sample data into the post not into images and let us know complete information what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Thanks for your advise, I have added the complete information..

Comment: Aha 1996, not bad!! 32bit integer support for that time was already great :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the second, showing 2147483647 is treating %d as 4byte integer where as the first PC is using more bytes, probably a long. It will depend how `awk` was compiled on that machine or the version of awk used.

check out: https://superuser.com/questions/646919/how-can-i-find-my-awk-version

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the version of both `awk` are the same?

1. Use `$awk --version` on both system
2. Then check the conversion format for number `OFMT/CONVFMT` `awk 'BEGIN { print "Conversion Format =", CONVFMT }'` on both systems

Answer (score 0):

The correct value does appear to be stored, it just can't be displayed as an integer with `%d`. Displaying it as a rounded float with `%.0f` seems to work around the issue:

```sh
$ echo 49420877107 \
  |awk '{print $1; print $1+0; printf "%d\n", $1; printf "%.0f", $1}'
49420877107
4.94209e+10
2147483647
49420877107
```

The first `print` treats it as a string, the second as a large number that defaults to scientific notation, the third as an integer, and the fourth as a float.

```sh
$ awk -W version 2>/dev/null || awk --version
mawk 1.3.4 20200120
Copyright 2008-2019,2020, Thomas E. Dickey
Copyright 1991-1996,2014, Michael D. Brennan

random-funcs:       srandom/random
regex-funcs:        internal
compiled limits:
sprintf buffer      8192
maximum-integer     2147483647
```

Answer (score -2):

This format should print the correct number (long integer):

```
echo 49420877107 \
  | awk '{printf("%ld\n", $1)}'
```

Comment: Using conversion qualifier `l` to tell awk this is a **l**ong integer is a nice idea, but it doesn't seem to be working in mawk 1.3.4, which prints `2147483647`. You're still better off with `%.0f` as noted in [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70902663/519360).